# pass session values in pagination

Tags: php, session, pagination

I can pass values form one page to another but I need to pass value like this,

Page 1:

Page2.php

Page3.php

I need to pass the radio button values in the Page1.php to Page2.php, and also i need to use same session . if the form is redirected to page3, I am unable to get the value of page 1. its online quiz project. I tried session, form post method and few other methods but I am yet to succeed.

I would be very happy if you can help me with the code or some suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: Post the session code you tried.

Comment: extract($_POST);


if(isset($Sumbitall))
{

$a=$_POST['Option'];
$_SESSION['x']=$a;   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your question is vague, first of all when you are using sessions, you need to be sure you are calling `session_start()` at the very top of the page, secondly, you can save the form data in your session variable like

```
if(isset($_POST['YOUR_SUBMIT_BUTTON_NAME_HERE'])) {
   $store_temp_val1 = $_POST['whatever']; //Sanitize the value first
   $_SESSION['page_one']['first_val'] = $store_temp_val1;
}
```

Now you can simply retrieve the value stored in the session variable on the second page like

```
echo $_SESSION['page_one']['first_val']; //Will echo the previous page value
```

---

> Note: Use `session_start()` on each page at the very top.

Comment: $_SESSION['page_one']['first_val'] = $store_temp_val1;  //in this method i can use only same session variables to page2, page3?

Comment: @G.d.Venu didn't got you

Comment: @G.d.Venu I guess you didn't understood the answer

Comment: sorry !.. for page1, one session['a'] variable  to get posted data.. and page 2 another session['b'] variable to get posted data.this is your suggestion .. am right ?

Comment: @G.d.Venu you will need a session array which will hold your data

Answer (score 1):

The best practice would be to go with OOP. So, you can do the following:

1. Create a class with fields to hold all the information you want to pass.

```
    class PageInfo
    {
       var $pageTitle;
       var $currentPage;
       var $btnValue;
       .....
    }
```

2.Now crate an object of `PageInfo` class, and assign the values you want to set.

```
    $page = new PageInfo();  
    $page->pageTitle = "Home";
    $page->btnValue  = 1;  
    ...
```

3.Assign this object (holding all the details of your page) to the super-global session variable.

```
    // store session data
    $_SESSION['page'] = $page;
```

4.Now you can access the value stored in the session at the different pages.

```
    $otherPage = $_SESSION['page'];
    echo $otherPage->pageTitle;
    echo $otherPage->btnValue;
```

**Note:** The `session_start()` function must appear BEFORE you print anyting on the page.